# How to redimension the SQL Server Database Size?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-vm

Moving SQL Server to Azure in a VM.

The current SQL Server has a total database size of 1.8TB, and 1.2TB of unallocated space.

How do I change the total database size, so it is more in line with what's been used?

So, when I restore the back-up inside the Azure VM, I don't end up over paying for storage space that I am not using.

Any lead is appreciated.

Comment: You would shrink it, though this is rarely a good idea, as it can severely fragment your data.

Comment: Presumably this is a one-off operation and I would attempt to shrink the database first and then back it up before restoring in Azure. Usially the best way would be to move the tables to new filegroup(s) then drop the empty ones, or then shrink the primary filegroup if it contained all the data previously, set to simple recovery and shrink the log to a reasonable size, of course there are various caveats and edge cases.

Comment: Are you looking for database sharding approach? Or better to go for Azure SQL where you can achieve this very easily.

Comment: You may find that the files grow back out to the same size after moving to Azure.  The database needs space in the data and log files to support normal operations - and for a 1.8TB database having 600GB may be reasonable.  For example, if you have a table that is 400GB+ in size and rebuild the index - the data file will grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate that extra space on data and log files, the process used is the Shrink File.
It can be found on SQL Server Management Studio, right clicking the database on Object Explorer, and navigating to Tasks > Shrink > Files, and then selecting the option "Reorganize pages before releasing unused space".
But for really large databases, like your case, this can take days to complete.
I've seen some databases get recreated, then all the data migrated, then all the indexes recreated, just to skip a Shrink Files process that was taking forever to finish.